# Java.time.LocalTime with zeros

Tags: java, time

I have this LocalTime formatter:

```
private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m");
```

I have only one H and only one m because otherwise I get am exception if hour or minutes are only one diget.
My question now would be how to add zeros if hour or minutes is only one digit. This is my current code:

```
final LocalTime localTime = 
  LocalTime.parse(duration.getStandardHours() + ":" + 
  (duration.getStandardMinutes() % 60), formatter);
```

Comment: I can see the sense in a one-digit hour, but why the one digit minutes? What kind of a format is that? Why are you converting from a duration to a `LocalTime` like that?

Comment: I think OP just wants to ensure zero padding on hours and minutes.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvotes...

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question should not really be about the format, but should explain the reason for using it. Why are Joda-Time and java.time objects mixed? What is the idea behind converting the duration first into hours and then into minutes (it's not the hours part and the minute part!), why is a duration (representing a length of time) converted into an object that represents the time-of-day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the LocalTime from the hours/minutes directly:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(duration.getStandardHours(),
                              duration.getStandardMinutes() % 60);
```

Also it seems that the `Duration` is from joda time - there is also a `Duration` in Java time so you may want to switch to that for consistency:

```
java.time.Duration duration = java.time.Duration.ofMinutes(67);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of((int) duration.toHours(), (int) duration.toMinutes() % 60);
System.out.println("time = " + time); //01:07
```